# Find last value of array in foreach cicle

Tags: php

I've data stored in a array ($rows).
For read the array and genarate a dinamic table I use foreach function.

```
<table>

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['field1'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['field2'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['filed3'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>"; 
    }

</table>
```

My goal is to find the last value of the array (the end) in order to change the class of TR element for the last line displayed.
How could I do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach ($rows as $key => $row) {
    $end = end($rows) === $row ? 'class="last"' : '';
    echo "<tr $end>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['field1'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['field2'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['filed3'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>"; 
}
```

This method works for multidimentional arrays as well.

http://codepad.org/HQG9ytBX

**Edit**. As pointed in comments, this approach may potentially trigger false end result if some values in the array are duplicated (with the last). Correct bullet-proof version should be:

```
foreach ($rows as $key => $row) {
    $end = end($rows) === $row && $key === key($rows) ? 'class="last"' : '';

    // ...
```

Comment: @YourCommonSense There is a possibility? I always used `end` for this task and it always worked as expected. Can you provide an example when it fails?

Comment: @PaoloRossi this solution is actually worst one, as it deals with array values, which are non-unique - thus, there is a possibility for the false triggering.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I see your point now. Thank you for valuable comment!

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
$is_last_row = ++$i == count($rows);
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['field1'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['field2'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['filed3'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>"; 
    }
```

here $i should be an unused variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$numItems = count($rows);
$i = 0;
foreach($rows as $row) {

$trClass = 'firstclass';
if(++$i === $numItems) 
{
$trClass = 'lastclass';
}


echo "<tr class='$trclass'>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['field1'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['field2'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['filed3'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// first, let's find out the last key
end($rows);
$last = key($rows);

// then just loop over
foreach ($rows as $key => $row) {
        if ($key == $last) {
            // last leaf of the summer...
        }
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['field1'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['field2'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['filed3'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>"; 
}
```